# Graddle Error Shows "Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'."

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Hello i had a problem with my project when i run it this message appear

> Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not find androidx.recycleview:recycleview:1.1.0.

and this my graddle looks like

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {
compileSdkVersion 30

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.mysubmission"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard- 
 rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
 }
}

dependencies {

implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.5.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
implementation 'androidx.recycleview:recycleview:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

I didnt know how to resolve it yet if someone know how to fix it i appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
implementation 'androidx.recycleview:recycleview:1.1.0'
```

with

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
```